# Consistency of object files generation

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a system, which splits source file by some criteria and compile each separated source file individualy. I guess there will be some duplicates among these files, and I wonder if I should implement some cache logic for this.

But I need much staff to implement this logic, like cmd, input file content, enviroment and maybe more. Things are even more complicated because it's supposed to be a feature of some noname open source build system.

So I decided to use just the content of the output file to collect some stats about duplicates. And firstly checked it with some code from my cpp project (with msvc) (no splitting, just pretty large generated unity file with tons of code, macroses and so on). The result was a bit flustrating as obj files for same cpp ( I checked generated cpp file content comparing it's hash values ) had same size but different contents.
I guess in my case I just need to implement classic cache and just skip this issue.

But I'm curious is this a normal behaviour? Same cpp, same machine, same args, different runs, different obj files? What can be the case for this?

Comment: This is compiler-dependent, so please tag the question with just _one_ compiler.

Comment: Don't forget to include headers in your question.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the command `g++ myprog.cpp` is running the same `g++` that it was running yesterday.  So no.

Comment: Why you are asking about that? This sounds like [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). By reading between lines I see undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: There is at least MACRO `__DATE__`, `__TIME__` which will make source using it different.

Comment: Have a read of [Nikhil's blog - Getting to Deterministic Builds on Windows](https://nikhilism.com/post/2020/windows-deterministic-builds/) It will help with some of the issues.  Also [Reproducible builds](https://reproducible-builds.org/) .